# Rational values of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, rational-numbers

I am using extensively trigonometric functions when an angle is given in degrees.
Some of these functions like sine or cosine have rational values, for example, the well   known example is that $\cos(\theta) =0.6 $ and $\sin(\theta) =0.8 $.

However besides the case of multiplicity of $90^\circ$ it seems there are no rational numbers $\theta$  with simultaneously rational  values of  sine and cosine.

- Is it possible somehow to prove that for rational values of an angle given **in degrees** there are  no values simultaneously rational of sine and cosine functions, beside obvious case of multiplicities of $90^\circ$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Niven's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensTheorem.html): If $x/\pi$ (in radians) and $\sin x$ are both rational, then the sine takes values $0$, $\pm 1/2$, and $\pm 1$.

Obviously, angle in radians is a rational multiple of $\pi$ iff angle in  degrees is rational.

Comment: Hmm, how to translate this theorem into degrees ?

Comment: @Widawensen, angle in degrees$/360$ = angle in radians$/2\pi$.

Comment: I'm starting  to understand, so it's enough to prove this Niven theorem (thank you for presenting it) - I wonder whether the proof of it is very complicated..

Comment: @Widawensen, the proof is nontrivial but elementary: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Niven's_Theorem.

Comment: That's what was needed.. amazing that it is not so complicated...

Comment: @Widawensen There is a different proof (maybe comparable comlpexity) that I prefer in  "When is the (co)sine of a rational angle equal to a rational number?": https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2938

Comment: @MarkS Also very interesting.. thank you..

Answer (score 2):

Let us take the Pythagorean theorem $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and divide both sides by $c^2$ to get $\frac{a^2}{c^2} + \frac{b^2}{c^2} = 1$. Now, we can use the well-known relationship between sine and cosine: $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2 (x) = 1$, and let $\sin(x) = \frac{a^2}{c^2}$, and $\cos(x) = \frac{b^2}{c^2}$.

Since the hypotenuse of a triangle is always longer than the two legs, $\frac{a^2}{c^2}, \frac{b^2}{c^2} < 1$. Therefore, there exists a bijection between one triplet of $a,b,c$ and $\frac{a^2}{c^2}, \frac{b^2}{c^2}$, and at least one value of $\frac{a^2}{c^2}, \frac{b^2}{c^2}$ for $\sin(x)$.

One example using a $3,4,5$ triangle shows that $\cos(x) = \frac{9}{25}$, and using the second equation $\sin(x) = \frac{16}{25}$. As a bonus, since there are [infinitely many Pythagorean triples](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/pythagorean-triples.html), this shows that there are infinitely many values of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ that are rational.

Comment: Thank you Toby for this answer but also $x$ expressed in **degrees** should be  rational. I don't know whether this is possible even though there are infinitely many Pythagorean triples ..

Comment: For my example using the 3-4-5 triangle, I know there is at least one solution according to Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsin(16/25), https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccos(9/25)

Comment: Sorry to everyone who expected my older answer, I found a way to shorten it massively by jumping straight into the Pythagorean theorem, rather than working through the identity $\sin^2 (x) + \cos^2 (x) = 1$ and using rational numbers.

Comment: @Widawensen I have to show that $\cos^{-1} (x)$ and $\sin^{-1} (x)$ are rational if $x$ is, which I cannot do with the knowledge that I have. Anyways, the previous answer probably expressed it better than I could have

Comment: Yes, this Niven's theorem with the provided link to its proof seems to answer the question very well, but your answer is also very informative so let's treat it as a partial one..

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realise I couldn't solve the problem until reviewing it. I thought I could go past the last step to prove the fact I needed, but I eventually found out I couldn't.

Comment: Explain the downvote.

Comment: Not me Toby, I value your answer and upvoted it..